# 2-torus as 3-fold branched cover of the 2-sphere, branched at six points

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, knot-theory

I think I understood the well-known construction of the 2-torus as double cover of the 2-sphere branched at two points: one pierces the torus with an axis, which intersects it four time, and identifies the pairs of points on the torus that are related by a 180° rotation around said axis. The four piercings are invariant under this identification, therefore they are branch points. The fundamental domain of this identification has the topology of a sphere with four points removed.

**My question is:** is there a similar intuitive construction that describes the 2-torus as a 3-fold covering of the sphere, branched at six points?

**Here's the context of my question:** I am interested in the description of a knot complement, which is a 3-sphere with a solid torus removed, as a branched covering. With the Heegaard splitting, I can describe any compact 3-manifold as two handle bodies of genus g, glued along their boundaries. Each handle body can be seen as a 3-fold branched covering of the 3-disk, branched along g+2 arcs ending at 2(g+2) points on the boundary of the disk.
In the case of the 3-sphere, I need two genus 1 handle bodies (two solid tori), which I see as three-fold coverings of the 3-disk, branched along 3 arcs ending at 6 points on its boundary sphere. The two tori are glued at their boundaries, and therefore so are the two 3-disks, and the six branch points on their boundaries are identified pairwise.
Now, if I want to do the same, but for a knot complement, I need to remove from the original 3-sphere a solid torus. I think this should correspond to removing a solid sphere from one of the 3-disks, and letting the three branching arcs end at six points on this new boundary I created (which is a 2-sphere).
So, the boundary of the knot complement, which is a torus, is seen as the three-fold covering of a 2-sphere, branched along six points.

Comment: Maybe not intuitive, but one way to construct such a covering is given by the derivative of the Weierstrass $\wp$ function, thought of as a function from a complex torus to the Riemann sphere

Comment: No if this works it's exactly what I need, an explicit example of triple cover that I can work out! Can you perhaps give me more details or provide a reference? The derivative of $\wp$ has six branch points within one domain of the lattice? And it's a triple cover of the Riemann sphere?

Comment: To be honest, I am not so sure about the number of branch points, but it is a triple cover of the Riemann sphere.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Any pointer where I can find the statement?

Comment: The fact that it has degree 3 follows from the fact that it has a unique pole of order 3

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I doubt that $\wp'$ has the right number of branch points. Sorry for leading you down a wrong path. It is an interesting and concrete example of a triple cover of the sphere by a torus, at least. Maybe someone who knows more about elliptic functions knows how one can solve this using an elliptic function?

Comment: Yeah if it has a single pole I suppose it means it only has one branching point. Thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: That's not necessarily the case: $\wp$ has a single pole and four branching points. But I still think that $\wp'$ has less than 6 branching points.